# Error en java: error: illegal start of expression

Tags: java

Apenas comienzo a programar en Java(nivel novato) y estoy haciendo una clase que se llama Persona; pero al compilar me arroja el siguiente error:

Persona.java:31: error: illegal start of expression
if (sexo != 'H') && (sexo != 'M'); s = "Desconocido";

Como lo puedo corregir ?, este es el codigo:

```
        class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private int edad;
    private char sexo;

    public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String txt) {
    nombre = txt;
    }
    public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
    }
    public void setApellido(String txt) {
    apellido = txt;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
    }
    public void setEdad(int n) {
    edad = n;
    }
    public String getSexo() {
    String s;
    if (sexo == 'H') s = "Hombre";
    if (sexo == 'M') s = "Mujer";
    if (sexo != 'H') && (sexo != 'M'); s = "Desconocido";
    return s;
    }
    public void setSexo(char s) {
        sexo = s;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Las condiciones deben ir dentro del `if`.  `if (sexo != 'H' && sexo != 'M') s = "Desconocido";` y hay un `;` de más.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba cambiando las tu método getSexo()...
En vez de que uses:

```
public String getSexo() {
    String s;
    if (sexo == 'H') s = "Hombre";
    if (sexo == 'M') s = "Mujer";
    if (sexo != 'H') && (sexo != 'M'); s = "Desconocido";
return s;
}
```

Prueba con:

```
public String getSexo() {
    String s = "";
    if (sexo == 'H') s = "Hombre";
    if (sexo == 'M') s = "Mujer";
    if (sexo != 'H' && sexo != 'M'){
        s = "Desconocido";
    } 
return s;
}
```

Esto sucede porque el método `if()` lo estabas escribiendo de la siguiente forma:
`if ()(){code...}` lo cual no existe.

De igual forma en tu método estás inicializando la variable con `s = "Desconocido"` por lo que te recomiendo que uses la estructura que eclipse o netbeans te mandan por default para facilitar que tú mismo entiendas tu código.

```
if(condition...){
    code...
}
```

Y en tu caso, recomendaría usar:

```
if(condition...){
    code...
} else if(condition...){
    code...
} else {
    code...
}
```

Espero que sea de ayuda mi respuesta.

Saludos!

Comment: Yo recomendaría  utilizar un switch-case para esa evaluación. A como van las cosas, probablemente necesite 200 if-else algún día. y se podría poner complicado.

Comment: @Arriel por el tipo de cuestión que se está realizando, insisto que el if es mejor. No pienso que el género sexual de alguien varíe entre hombre, mujer o desconocido si no se pone un input. El switch-case lo usaría si existen más posibilidades de inputs. Manejando esto yo lo pondría con un combobox que tenga las opciones hombre, mujer en un campo que permita null en una base de datos para aceptar el “desconocido”...

Comment: Comprendo tu punto y llevas razón. Pero te pongo el siguiente caso de uso: Vives en Canadá y trabajas para el gobierno canadiense y ellos desean que, dadas las leyes de inclusión de género, no deberás limitarte a hombre/mujer y debes permitir más de 10 géneros. Qué haces en ese caso?

Comment: En eso estoy de acuerdo contigo. Ni lo discuto. Gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias Gonzalo!, apenas estoy iniciando en esto y creo que tu leccion es muy buena para un novato como yo. Saludos!

Comment: Ya se pudo complilar Gonzalo!, gracias de nuevo.